# how to store and update value of an object in local storage without creating another key using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, local-storage

```js
const person={name:'',userPoints:0,computerPoints:0,Tie:0};
function evaluateResult(a,b){
    if(a == 'rock' && b == scissor){
     
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML="You Win";
        userpoints=userpoints+1;
        document.getElementById('userscore').innerHTML=userpoints;
        
    }
    else if(a == 'scissor' && b == rock){
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML="You Lose";
        computerpoints=computerpoints+1;
        document.getElementById('compscore').innerHTML=computerpoints;
    }
    else if(a == 'scissor' && b == paper){
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML="You Win";
        userpoints=userpoints+1;
        document.getElementById('userscore').innerHTML=userpoints;
    
    }
    else if(a == 'paper' && b == scissor){
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML="You Lose";
        computerpoints=computerpoints+1;
        document.getElementById('compscore').innerHTML=computerpoints;
       
     }
    else if(a == 'paper' && b == rock){
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML="You Win";
        userpoints=userpoints+1;
        document.getElementById('userscore').innerHTML=userpoints;
       
    }
    else if(a == 'rock' && b == paper){
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML="You Lose";
        computerpoints=computerpoints+1;
        document.getElementById('compscore').innerHTML=computerpoints;
       
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML="It\'s a Tie";
        tie++;
       
    }
 }
```

Suppose I have created a person object now I have to save and update the value of each key in local storage. When my function evaluateResult give an output then i want to store that result in my local storage on each iteration
Is it possible to update the value of each key on every click?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From two comments to the OP's own answer ...

> *"Regardless of the possible solution found by the OP, the posted/provided code twice is full of type errors e.g. missing quotes for all `b` related comparisons like with `b == scissor`, `b == rock` and so on ... in addition the entire `if...else` logic could be much more simplified by a lookup based approach. "*

> *"Another point ... since the OP generates a user, most probably an object from the stored stringified version of a user's (previous?) gaming score(s), this score needs to be addressed somehow in the code of `evaluateResult` ... a `user` object e.g. could look like this ... `{ scoreCounts: { won: 0, lost: 0, tie: 0 } }`."*

... and the suggested possible improvements from above put into an executable/running code example ...

```js
function evaluateResult(scores, player, computer) {
  function playerWins() {
    console.log("You Win");
    ++scores.won;

    //document.getElementById('demo').textContent = "You Win";
    //document.getElementById('userscore').textContent = ++scores.won;
  }
  function computerWins() {
    console.log("You Lose");
    ++scores.lost;

    //document.getElementById('demo').textContent = "You Lose";
    //document.getElementById('compscore').textContent = ++scores.lost;
  }
  function itsATie() {
    console.log("It's a Tie");
    ++scores.tie;

    //document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML="It's a Tie";
    //++scores.tie;
  }

  (({
    // an ad hoc generated
    // object based lookup table ...

    paper_rock: playerWins,
    rock_scissor: playerWins,
    scissor_paper: playerWins,

    rock_paper: computerWins,
    scissor_rock: computerWins,
    paper_scissor: computerWins,

    // ... which immediately gets
    // accessed by a composed key ...
    //                            ... with tie fallback ...
    //                                      ... and invoked.

  }[ [player, computer].join('_') ]) ?? itsATie).call();
}

const user = {
  scoreCounts: {
    won: 0,
    lost: 0,
    tie: 0,
  },
};
console.log('user ... before evaluate ...', user);

evaluateResult(user.scoreCounts, 'rock', 'paper');
evaluateResult(user.scoreCounts, 'paper', 'rock');
evaluateResult(user.scoreCounts, 'paper', 'paper');
evaluateResult(user.scoreCounts, 'scissor', 'scissor');

console.log('user ... after evaluate ...', user);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

function evaluateResult(a,b){

```
var user=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('person'));

if(a == 'rock' && b == scissor){
 
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML="You Win";
    userpoints=userpoints+1;
    document.getElementById('userscore').innerHTML=userpoints;
   
       user.userPoints+=1;
       localStorage.setItem('person',JSON.stringify(user));
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

<<<>>>
The above code represents only first case which explains the answer that how to store  and update the value of an object without using another key

Comment: Regardless of the possible solution found by the OP, the posted/provided code twice is full of type errors e.g. missing quotes for all `b` related comparisons like with `b == scissor`, `b == rock` and so on ... in addition the entire `if...else` logic could be much more simplified by a lookup based approach.

Comment: Another point ... since the OP generates a user, most probably an object from the stored stringified version of a user's (previous?) gaming score(s), this score needs to be addressed somehow in the code of `evaluateResult` ... a `user` object e.g. could look like this ... `{ scoreCounts: { won: 0, lost: 0, tie: 0 } }`.